# Comparing vector bundle degrees coming from different embeddings into projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-space, kahler-manifolds, holomorphic-bundles

This question is a follow-up to this recent question of mine:

[Comparing notions of degree of vector bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095420/)

In that question, the definition of the degree of a vector bundle is discussed — in particular, the complications of doing so when the base complex manifold has dimension larger than $1$.

In that question, the "degree" of a vector bundle $V$ on a $d$-dimensional complex projective variety $X\stackrel{\kappa}{\to}\mathbb P^n$ (where $d\leq n$) was defined to be the number

$\deg_\kappa(V)=c_1(\kappa^*\mathcal O(1))^{d-1}.c_1(V)$,

where $\mathcal O(1)$ is the hyperplane bundle on $\mathbb P^n$.  The subscript in $\deg_\kappa$ is not usual notation, but for the purpose of this question, I want to emphasize that the degree here depends on the embedding $\kappa$.

If we have two embeddings $\kappa:X\to\mathbb P^n$ and $\iota:X\to\mathbb P^m$ (where necessarily $d\leq m,n$), is it true that $\deg_\kappa(V)>0$ if and only if $\deg_\iota(V)>0$?  If so, why?

Also, since smooth projective varieties are Kähler, if we were to define the degree of $V$ using the Kähler class on $X$ instead of $\kappa$, would the degree defined using the Kähler class have the same sign as $\deg_\kappa(V)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V = \mathcal{O}(1,-1)$ on $X = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. Let the two embeddings be from the line bundles $\mathcal{O}(n,1)$ and $\mathcal{O}(1,n)$.

The degree of $V$ is $1-n$ for the first embedding and $n-1$ for the second. So, no.

I don't know the answer to your second question.

Comment: Thanks.  Which projective space are we embedding into?  I believe $\mathcal O(n,1)$ and $\mathcal O(1,n)$ each have $(n+1)\times(1+1)=2n+2$ independent global sections, and so the embeddings should be into $\mathbb P^{2n+1}$?  (For $n=1$, I take it that we get the Segre embedding of $\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1$ as a smooth quadric in $\mathbb P^3$?)

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, is it possible to cook up such an example (where the degree changes sign with the embedding) when $X$ isn't a ruled surface or Cartesian product of two varieties etc.  The bi-degree of line bundles on $\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1$ is essential to this counter-example....

Comment: @MathsByTheSea: Very welcome! Yes, the embeddings are into $\mathbb{P}^{2n+1}$. The map is the degree-$n$ Veronese embedding on one of the $\mathbb{P}^1$ factors, Segre-ed together with the identity map on the other $\mathbb{P}^1$.

I don't think this example is special. The main ingredient is to have a divisor class group of rank >1, so that we can have two different types of divisors to play with. (Then it's just a matter of taking the right linear combinations to have the sign change). The case $X = \mathbb{P}^n$ is highly unusual in that $\mathrm{Pic}(X) = \mathbb{Z}$.